# Kibana - Splitting series by field names

Tags: kibana, visualization, linechart

I was hoping to find a way to split a series by field names (and not values of a particular field) in kibana

I have a data set that looks like below:

*{ { date: 24/06/2021, foo: 12, bar: 20}, { date: 24/06/2021, foo: 16, bar: 20}, { date: 25/06/2021, foo: 16, bar: 20}, { date: 25/06/2021, foo: 16, bar: 20} }*

I was hoping to see something like this:

1. Date on the x-axis and
2. the average of 'foo' for that date as one point and average of 'bar' as another point on a timeseries line chart. (essentially having field values of the same document as different series(es))

Is this possible?

Context: I am importing the document from a csv and the field names ('foo' and 'bar') are columns in the csv. I have managed to get what I need by adding a 'type' column on the csv and setting its values to be 'foo' and 'bar'

example:
*{ { date: 24/06/2021, val: 12, type: foo}, { date: 24/06/2021, val: 20, type: bar} ... }*

and splitting the series by the 'type' field, but I wanted to know if there was a way to create the chart without having to edit the csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using Kibana Lens visualization. It allows me to set Y-axis with different fields from the same document